# How do synchronize coredata and sqlite?

Tags: ios, mysql, json, swift, xcode

I am making an app that takes button clicks (`true or false alarm`), and then appending which button is clicked, the date of the click into a `UITableView`. All of this information is currently being stored in the coredata, and I would like to upload the data from the table/coredata to sqlite. I would like to then upload this table to a database so that it can be used for other things.

I have tried using `JSONSerialization` but I am unsure as to how it works. I would like to send the `json` file to the database with a button view, but I could not give a `UIButton` this function.

For the button inputs,

```
@IBAction func addAlarm(_ sender: UIButton){
    let trueFalseAlarm = Alarm(context: moc)
    trueFalseAlarm.added = Date()

    if sender.tag == 0{
        trueFalseAlarm.trueFalse = "0""
    }else if sender.tag == 1{
        trueFalseAlarm.trueFalse = "1"
}
```

}

the Table View:

```
func tableView (_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(with Identifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let trueFalseAlarm = alarmItems[indexPath.row]
    let trueFalse = trueFalseAlarm.trueFalse
    cell.deatailTextLabel?.text = trueFalse
    let alarmDate = trueFalseAlarm.added as! Date
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    date Formatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM yyyy, hh:mm"

    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateFormatter.string(from: alarmDate)
```

The table works, but now the problem is getting an instance of the table at the point of time, and send that array that is used in the UITableView and upload it to the database. The array currently looks like this:

> alarmItems: [ (entity: Alarm; id: _____
>    ; data: {added = "2019-05-24 02:17:51
>   +0000"; trueFalse = 0;}), ... ]

The data in the tableview is stored inside the coredata. Is it possible to upload/synchronize the data from coredata and have it in sqlite also?
All I need is everything after data. Thank you so much.